# Lokpal Act and Jan Lokpal Bill, what's the difference between these two bills?

Tags: india, corruption, civil-rights, specific-legislation

What's the difference between the anti-corruption [Lokpal Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lokpal_and_Lokayuktas_Act,_2013) and [Jan Lokpal Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Lokpal_Bill) in Indian Politics?

Comment: Can you please clarify what answer you seek beyond info on Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lokpal , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lokpal_and_Lokayuktas_Bill,_2013 , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Lokpal_Bill

Comment: @DVK, sure. thanks for that link, just another question, how it is different from the "JAN LOKPAL BILL".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we know, Jan Lokpal Bill is the bill that was proposed by Anna Hazare and team. While the Lokpal Bill is Government's version of the bill that actually got passed. This is also referred to as joke-pal bill by Arvind Kejriwal.

Below is the comparison taken from [this article](http://www.whatreallymatters.in/2013/12/the-joke-pal-and-lokpal-game.html).

[image: Jan-Lokpal and Lokpal bill]

Hope that helps!